# Сколько можно отфильтровать ботов с помощью iptables + ipset?

Tags: ddos, linux

Сколько можно отфильтровать ботов с помощью iptables + ipset. И стоит ли использовать сию связку вообще?

Answer (score 1):

неплохо справляется fail2ban

Comment: Не много не корректный ответ.

Comment: файл2бан все одно сидит на иптаблес, поэтому я его и рекомендовал.